# Application_BeginRequest Usage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

we are trying some login operations in our ASP.NET MVC project. Our goal is : "**If user's IP is not from our intranet, redirect him/her to login page. Else, just go to our index page**. We wrote some code but we are inside a loop.

## GLOBAL.ASAX

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var request = ((System.Web.HttpApplication) sender).Request;

        string ip1 = request.UserHostAddress;
        string shortLocalIP;
        if (ip1 != null && ip1.Contains("."))
        {
            string[] ipValues = ip1.Split('.');
            shortLocalIP = ipValues[0] +"."+ipValues[1];
        }
        else
        {
            shortLocalIP = "192.168";
        }

        //var ip2 = request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"];
        //var ip3 = request.ServerVariables["SERVER_ADDR"];

        if (shortLocalIP != LOCALIP)
        {
            if ("/Login/User".Equals(request.RawUrl, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {                   
                    return;                                  
            }

            Response.Clear();            
            Response.Redirect("/Login/User");             
            Response.End();       
        }
    }
```

## LOGIN CONTROLLER

```
 public class LoginController : Controller
{
    // GET: Login
    public ActionResult User()
    {         
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult checkAuthentication(FormCollection collection)
    {
        bool isAuthenticated = new LdapServiceManager().isAuthenticated(collection);
        if (isAuthenticated)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Home/Index");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("/Login/User");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

## LOGIN CSHTML

```
 <form class="login-form" action="/Login/checkAuthentication" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

Application_BeginRequest triggers everytime when we press some button or something else. But we want these operations at the beginning only. Thanks...

**Should we use SESSION START in GLOBAL.ASAX??**

Comment: What do you mean "at the beginning"? The first time this user opens your application? But then what is "this user"? A user from this particular IP? then you need to check IP on every request... which is exactly what you are doing!

Comment: I mean if you open my page, we check your IP. If your ip is coming from our network, go to index. If your ip is not coming from our network, direct the page to loginPage. In loginPage we want input from user. When user press login button, it redirect loginPage again because of application_beginRequest

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `ActionFilter` for this. Create a class for custom filter, something like this -

```
public class IntranetAction : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        bool isIPAddressValid = false;//TODO: Check the IP validity here
        if (isIPAddressValid)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                controller = "Account", //TODO - Edit as per you controller
                action = "Login"        //and Action
            }));
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

And simply use it over your controller `ActionMethod` like this for example -

```
    [IntranetAction]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Suugest to go through a good article to get started with custom filters - http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

Comment: I cant write IntranetAction on top of my function

Comment: @Berkin `IntranetAction` is the custom filter that we created. Make sure the name is correct and you are referencing the correct namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

Application_BeginRequest will be called on every request made to your server. If you want to execute some logic only on certain action use [ActionFilters](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **ActionFilter** for MVC. Here is the sample code for the operation.

```
public class IpControlAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
    private const string LOCALIP = "";

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        var request = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;

        string ip1 = request.UserHostAddress;
        string shortLocalIP;
        if (ip1 != null && ip1.Contains(".")) {
            string[] ipValues = ip1.Split('.');
            shortLocalIP = ipValues[0] + "." + ipValues[1];
        } else {
            shortLocalIP = "192.168";
        }

        //var ip2 = request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"];
        //var ip3 = request.ServerVariables["SERVER_ADDR"];

        if (shortLocalIP != LOCALIP) {
            if ("/Login/User".Equals(request.RawUrl, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {
                return;
            }

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Account/Login");
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to add it as global filter in **FilterConfig.cs**

```
filters.Add(new IpCheckAttribute());
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Teşekkürler :) I create a class which has name FilterConfig.cs into App_Start folder. But i didnt understand last part. Where should i write filters.add part? In global.asax -> Application_Start function?

Comment: Do remember that adding it as global filter will make it execute for all action. Take caution.

Comment: no in mvc application there is a folder named, **App_Start**. Under that there is **FilterConfig** file. Add that code there. On the other hand @Yogi mentions it will used for every action. If you want to specify for specific action you need to write it to controllers or actions like
`[IpCheck]
public class HomeController:Controller{}`

Comment: A bit late for answer!